# Can I access the OWIN environment dictionary?

Tags: asp.net-core, owin

Can I access the OWIN environment dictionary in ASP.NET Core?

I would like to access it from the `Startup.cs` file.

The reason I want to access it is because I want to pass the OWIN environment dictionary to my middleware or access it from within my middleware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can!

First install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` package.

Then from anywhere you got an instance of `HttpContext` you can create a instance of the `OwinEnvironment` class with the HttpContext as parameter to the constructor.

```csharp
var environment = new OwinEnvironment(HttpContext);
```

This doesn't have any indexer so you cant do `environment["owin.RequestProtocol"]`, but you can do:

```csharp
var requestProtocol = environment.Single(x => x.Key == Owin.RequestProtocol");
```

However, you can make it into a dictionary with `.ToDictionary` by doing:

```csharp
var dictionary = environment.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Now it has a indexer and you refer to keys like `environment["owin.RequestProtocol"]` to get the value.

There is also the `OwinFeatureCollection` class that you can feed the environment to to get out a dictionary.

```csharp
var environment = new OwinEnvironment(HttpContext);
var features = new OwinFeatureCollection(environment);
var requestProtocol = features["owin.RequestProtocol"];
```

However, there is no [`OWinContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.owincontext(v=vs.113).aspx) for strongly-typed accessors anymore in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin`, that is in the `Microsoft.Owin` namespace in a different package.

Answer (score 2):

I have come to believe that the OWIN environment is only available by installing the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` which exposes the `UseOwin` extension method to the `IApplicationBuilder` class.

Then it is available only in [`Startup.cs`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/startup.html#the-startup-class) from the `Configure` method as a parameter passed to your method by `app.UseOwin`.

I could not find the OWIN environment dictionary anywhere in `Controller`, `ControllerBase`, `HttpContext`, or `ControllerContext`. `HttpContext` has a `Items` dictionary though.

You could manually build an own OWIN environment yourself though using the data you find in `HttpContext`. But only from inside `app.UseOwin`.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/owin.html#owin-keys

A stock OWIN environment in ASP.NET Core with the additional `AspNetCore.Owin` package looks like the following:

```
[owin.RequestProtocol, HTTP/1.1]
[owin.RequestScheme, http]
[owin.RequestMethod, GET]
[owin.RequestPathBase, ]
[owin.RequestPath, /]
[owin.RequestQueryString, ]
[owin.RequestHeaders, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.DictionaryStringArrayWrapper]
[owin.RequestBody, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameRequestStream]
[owin.RequestUser, ]
[owin.ResponseStatusCode, 200]
[owin.ResponseReasonPhrase, ]
[owin.ResponseHeaders, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.DictionaryStringArrayWrapper]
[owin.ResponseBody, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.ScriptInjectionFilterStream]
[server.OnSendingHeaders, System.Action`2[System.Action`1[System.Object],System.Object]]
[server.ConnectionId, 0HKV72R0U3SDL]
[server.LocalPort, 27417]
[server.RemotePort, 56374]
[server.LocalIpAddress, 127.0.0.1]
[server.RemoteIpAddress, ::1]
[server.User, ]
[owin.CallCancelled, System.Threading.CancellationToken]
[owin.Version, 1.0]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext]
```

Points:

- OWIN is not part of ASP.NET Core.
- ASP.NET Core MVC is not built atop of OWIN.
- Support for OWIN can be added to ASP.NET Core using the `AspNetCore.Owin` package.

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling to find these keys.